# Fancy Buttons like WinZip

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, c#-4.0

In winzip buttons as highlighted, clicking on the button open Menus..

Is it possible in c# or VB.NET Window Form Application?

I am using c# 4.0 2010

[image]

Comment: BTW, which .NET version are you targeting? It's a lot more important than the language version.

Comment: That's not the .NET version. Visual Studio 2010 can target .NET 2.0, 3.5 and 4.0.

Comment: the NET toolstrip button allows drop down menus and that flat style

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to roll (make) your own controls, hereby thus a button control that handles "hover" and also takes into account to add an image.

You have two (maybe three) options:

1. I'd say search on codeproject.com for several tutorials on how to make your own buttons.
   e.g.: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29010/WinForm-ImageButton
2. Buy a thrid party product (such as the controls from Telerik.com for example).
3. (maybe try playing with the "Flatstyle" option on the Button: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.buttonbase.flatstyle(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: 4) use a plain old button, put an image on it, set text align to below. and UseVisualStyles for things like `Hot', `PushState` and the like